# Button's size and positions

Tags: android, button, user-interface, position, screen

I'm designing a simple UI for a calculator: some buttons and a text field for input/output view. I use a relative layout (in order to put the buttons at the bottom of the layout) but they don't occupy all the entire screen so with devices with big screens the buttons are really small. If I use linear layout I can occupy all the spaces but I can't put them in their positions.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: if you are using `px` change that to `dp`

Comment: You can set gravity as a bottom

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, but Shayan I already used dp and Manidroid if I use gravity as a bottom, the buttons superimpose one above the other.

Comment: Try to use gridview with autoFill property

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `LinearLayout` components with `weightSum` attribute. Let's say you have 1-9 numbers there for start.

```
7 8 9
4 5 6
1 2 3
```

The root layout would be vertical `LinearLayout` with `weightSum="3"`

Inside that three horizontal `LinearLayout` with `weightSum="3"` and `layout_weight="1"` which all have 3 `Button` with `layout_weight="1"`

Some xml to get you started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
etc..
```

Comment: Thank you Niko, I have a question: if I use this method, the buttons are in order and the size it's good but at the top of the screen. How can I put them at the bottom? Thank you

Comment: This depends little bit how you use the code, do you want it to have wrap_content height for all the buttons, or some static like 60% of screen height. If you modify the layout to use wrap_content heights and add android:layout_gravity="bottom" to the root, you wrap it into screen size FrameLayout or add it into RelativeLayout and use alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: This is basic layouting so I recommend you to figure it out how attributes affects on the layout instead of copy pasteing solution, it will definitely help you out understanding how the UI framework works and later designing custom components is way easier.

Comment: Ok, Niko thank you very much, your guidelines are very useful, I'll play with properties and attributes.